# What to do about an editor who has removed a lot of tags incorrectly

Tags: support, tags, serial-editing, bulk-tagging

Yesterday and today, I've seen a slew of edits from a [low-rep user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141418/ih8) who has been removing the [amd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amd) tag from a lot of questions (of the order of a 100 or so by my reckoning) that shouldn't have used the tag. The edit is technically correct as the questions were about the AMD processor, which is not what the tag is for.

However there is an [amd-processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amd-processor) tag, so the editor should have replaced the incorrect tag with the correct one. Unfortunately, I and other reviewers have let this get through for a lot of the edits so there are quite a few questions that no longer have an "AMD" tag.

Is there some way of bulk editing these questions to put the correct tag back, or is just a lesson to be learned?

(Out of guilt, I've started to manually add the correct tag back to the edits I approved).

EDIT: Looks like I don't need to bother, as the editor has now started to re-edit the incorrectly approved posts, and put the correct tag in place.

Comment: I just saw this as well.  The one thing to do here: Reject and edit it with the proper tag.  Don't just reject it.  EDIT: [they've started trying to add the right tags as well](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6255745).

Comment: @Pokechu22 Yeah I was rejecting and telling the user to replace with the correct tag. It's good to see that the user is now doing it correctly. So it's just the edits that got through earlier that need fixing.

Comment: Why don't you ask him why he is doing this @iH8

Comment: @remus Isn't this the idea of gamification to motivate and reward active members? You shouldn't reject edits or whatever just because you are upset about somebody earning currency too easy. As long as it is an (even a slightly) improving contribution everything is ok, in my view...

Comment: @matheburg It's worse: "You shouldn't reject edits or whatever just because you are upset **about your assumption** that somebody is earning currency too easy". DeanOC: Nothing indicates that this was intentional playing for rep.

Comment: Good points guys.

Comment: @matheburg  I definitely think that the member was genuinely trying to clean up the tag. The problem was that he was going about it the wrong way, and I (and others) allowed a lot of questions to be edited incorrectly. The fact that he was getting a lot of rep doesn't bother me.

Comment: @DeanOC I got the situation that way. My comment what just referred to remus' comment :)

Comment: I noticed only one of these edits.  While looking at the wiki to judge the review, I noticed that this tag is duplicated.  I'm going to post a synonym request soon.

Comment: This is my bad guys, and i'm very sorry. If someone pointed this out to me this could have been avoided. I wasn't even aware i could get rep for this untill the points rolled in. Somebody made a comment to one of the edited post but this was long after i saw my mistake and started to do it the correct way. I've got some 30 or some left of which i only removed the AMD tag, i'de love to add the correct one now but since this is seen as a "lurk", i'm not sure. Please advise.

Comment: @iH8 Sorry about the "lurk" remark. I've removed it. The fact that you get extra points is fine by me, as that's just the way the site works. You've shown that your intentions are honourable by changing your edits once you were made aware of the issue. I was only raising this question to see if there was some "system" functionality to clean up the earlier ones without someone having to do it one-by-one. If you're happy to go back and do it, then you deserve something for your efforts.

Comment: One by one is the way it goes.

Comment: I took no offense, i'm glad i spotted this discussion. If the person who commented on my edited post would have referred me to this discussion that would have been very helpful. He/She told me there was a discussion going on but didn't say where. Again sorry for the work i've caused, i was reading through the AMD tag because i'm interested in the topic and was kind of distracted and annoyed by all the processor/gpu questions in there so i decided to take a stab at cleaning that tag up.

Comment: @iH8 Make sure you properly document why the +tag is occurring with no -tag if you decide to fix the rest. Robo reviewers may automatically move to reject a valid fix to the tagging issue.

Comment: @Compass, i'de be happy to correct them. I created the problem, so it's the least i can do.  I've skimmed over them and turns out there are still quite a few to be done. The first i looked at were all corrected, but the further i go, the less are. Seems i've done a lot. Must have been in the zone or something. But that's no problem, i'll correct them all as soon as possible. My apologies (to all of you)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you said yourself the edit was *technically correct*, so there's no reason to reject it. But ...

- **Improve edit** to add the correct tag. [*]
- **Notify the editor** that he should add the correct tag himself in future.
  You can notify someone who suggested an edit by a comment with the `@user` notation (although he doesn't appear in the dropdown).

**OR**

- **Skip** the review and let others do the work.

---

[*] Previously we had a rejection reason called *Too Minor*, but as it turned out edits were too often rejected based on reviewers' bias. The [new policy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/) is to approve everything which actually makes the post better. And removing wrong tags makes posts better in my opinion (of couse adding the correct tag would be even better).

Comment: This would definitely be a valid approach, for a single edit. However the member was proposing a big number of these edits, which would mean a lot of work for the reviewer if your approach was adopted. The easier approach (for me) was to reject the edit, and put a note as to what I thought needed to be changed to make it valid. Then the proposer could decide if they wanted to do the work or not.

Comment: @DeanOC: "a lot of work for the reviewer" isn't a rejection reason. If you don't want to clean up after them, there is always the *Skip* button.

Comment: "removing wrong tags makes posts better". Not if it makes it harder to find the posts to attach the correct tags later.

Comment: @Boann that's probably less toxic that leaving the wrong tag.

Comment: @Boann: Because of that the best approach is to improve the edit. We only try to improve posts, not lazy reviewers.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer Even better if the suggesting editor does it right in the first place, which they will if their half edits are rejected.

Comment: @Boann: Don't punish them for playing by main site rules only. Notify them that there's a better way and link to the Meta discussion.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer I doubt they give a damn. Mass suggested editors are only ever in it for the rep.

Comment: As a note, while it isn't obvious and doesn't appear in the dropdown, one can actually notify someone who suggested an edit with the `@user` notation (which isn't an option for other users).

Comment: What is the proper way to "notify the editor" in such a case? SO doesn't have private messaging

Comment: @MattMcNabb. See the comment directly above yours.

Comment: "The new policy is to approve everything which actually makes the post better" No.

Comment: @bjb568 _"...while ensuring that truly helpful edits – even small ones – are more consistently approved."_ [Yes.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/10/new-editing-badges-and-enhancements-to-suggested-edits/) The current guideline is if it makes the post better, even if it is a small edit, approve it.

Comment: @Kendra That's simply incorrect. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238226/edit-reviewers-dont-know-how-to-review-because-nobody-told-them#comment781334_238325

Comment: @bjb568 If you're going to counter with another post, please post one from _after_ the one I posted. Otherwise, you're looking at the _reasons the one I pointed to was done._ Also, in the answer above that comment: _"Approve edits that clearly improve the post"_ and _"Reject edits that fail to improve the post or make it worse"_

Comment: @Kendra What "official" post are you referencing?

Comment: @bjb568: Your link actually supports that "too minor" isn't a rejection reason...

Comment: @Kendra Shog's answer above the comment I linked to is referring to the old edit system. His answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238039/) is newer. "Your edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed."

Comment: @Kendra Oh sorry, the grey link looked a lot like a notalink. I think that's talking about people rejecting as "too minor" out of spite. Truly helpful edits shouldn't be rejected, but that doesn't apply to these edits.

Comment: @bjb568 That's understandable then. And even the second answer you linked is older than the blog I linked to. If you can find a post from SE Staff that is more recent than the blog and supports your point, I will gladly concede. On that note, how does removing a tag that does not apply not improve the post?

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer It does? Why would you want to build upon it tho? I'd throw it away.

Comment: But I'd want to see the post in the previous state to quickly get an idea of it in my mind.

Comment: Good grief, this is an unproductive discussion thus far. The tl;dr of all those posts is: if the edit adds so little you don't mind discarding it in favor of your own, then click "reject and edit". If you think it was helpful but want to build on it, click "approve and edit". If you think it's worthless, click "Reject". If it's helpful and you can't add anything, click "Approve". Guess I really should just put all this on the review page.

Comment: @Shog9 That's what I feature-requested… :P The review page is where that belongs.

Answer (score -2):

The correct review action for these is to Reject and Edit, with the edit adding the relevant tag (and preferably improving other things too).

For when they're adding back the right tag, you should in most cases Reject and Edit to improve more aspects of the post. If you are sure the post is absolutely flawless, approving is fine.

Comment: That all seems reasonable up until the "you can skip" part. If I couldn't find an error, and the editor is adding back the right tag, then I would be inclined to accept the edit.

Comment: @DeanOC Meh, all right, edited, it was geared more toward robo-approvers.